# HSQLDB Trigger Syntax - is it impossible to make subqueries inside a trigger?

Tags: sql, syntax, hsqldb

I have a weird problem with a trigger in HSQLDB.  I've checked the syntax several times but I haven't found any mistakes.  I now think that it may be impossible to create a subquery inside a trigger.

This is the code:

```
create trigger activate_member after update on member
        REFERENCING OLD AS old NEW AS new
        for each row
        begin atomic
                IF new.active = FALSE AND old.active = TRUE then
                        insert into member_inactive
                            (
                                member,
                                since,
                                until
                        )
                        values (
                                new.id,
                                (select since from member_active where
member = new.id AND since = (select max(since) from member_active where
member = new.id group by member)),
                                curdate()
                        );
                ELSEIF new.active = TRUE AND old.active = FALSE then
                        insert into member_active (member, since) values
(new.id, curdate());
                end if;
        end;
```

I think I've made everything correct: I have semicolons on every query inside the `IF` and `ELSIEF` statements, and trailing semicolon after `end if`.

But I still get this error message:

```
SEVERE  SQL Error at 'database.sql' line 125:
"create trigger activate_member after update on member
        REFERENCING OLD AS old NEW AS new
        for each row 
        begin atomic
                IF new.active = FALSE AND old.active = TRUE then
                        insert into member_inactive 
                        (
                                member, 
                                since, 
                                until
                        ) 
                        values (
                                new.id, 
                                (select since from member_active where member = new.id AND since = (select max(since) from member_active where member = new.id group by member)), 
                                curdate()
                        )"
unexpected end of statement:  required: ; : line: 17
org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool$SqlToolException
```

But where I should add a semicolon? I think the problem is the subquery inside the `insert`, but that makes no sense.

Probably the `begin atomic` is problematic. But I see no other way to have an if-else statement inside a trigger without it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found now whats caused this problem: hsqldb only has `begin atomic` blocks inside a trigger.
Inside a `begin atomic` block i cannot use `insert` statements...

i now changed it to two triggers with `where (statement)` clauses, this works also

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the ";" after "curdate()"?
Hopefully that helps you with that problem.

Comment: nope that does not make sense at all, because its inside the insert statement... `unexpected end of statement:  required: ) : line: 16
`

Answer (score 0):

You may get a problem related to the use of new.id in the nested subquery in the VALUES clause of the INSERT statements.

Create a variable and assign the computed "SINCE" column to this, then use this variable in the VALUES list.

But at second glance, it looks the issue may relate to the software you use to execute the script, which cuts off the statement when it finds a semicolon. If you are using SqlTool, please use the latest version of the software and check the Guide on using RAW mode to avoid this issue.

Comment: i may found now whats caused this problem: hsqldb only has `begin atomic` blocks inside a trigger Inside a `begin atomic` block i cannot use insert statements... i now changed it to two triggers with `where (statement)` clauses, this works also